# Cobertura with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, cobertura

Has Cobertura been known to be used for code coverage in a JavaScript codebase? 
http://cobertura.github.io/cobertura/ says that it is for java codebase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can generate cobertura compatible file for Javascript too.

Some of frameworks that can generate cobertura formats are:

- [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/coverage.html)
- [TheIntern](https://theintern.io/intern/#reporter-lcov)
- [Mocha using Istanbul](https://istanbul.js.org/docs/tutorials/mocha/)

Answer (score 4):

Cobertura is **not known** to be used for JavaScript. JavaScript uses `lcov` or a custom `json` coverage output.

> Python and Java (not javascript) use Cobertura.

Checkout these example projects that produce coverage reports:
- [Javascript](https://github.com/codecov/example-node)
- [Python](https://github.com/codecov/example-python)
- [Java](https://github.com/codecov/example-java)

Thank you!

Comment: apparently this repo uses it https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js

Comment: It looks like the distinction here is, as @sergiogarciadev remarks, whether you're using the Cobertura _output format_ to report results for downstream tools or actually using the Cobertura coverage _tool_ to create that file.  You could use the _format_ with any sort of coverage report, including JavaScript, but the _tool_ is only for Java.